# Get the focussed element on focus change

Tags: javascript, focus

I'm trying to keep a record of the last text input element that had focus. My code:

```
document.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    var obj = document.activeElement;
    if(obj instanceof HTMLInputElement && obj.type == 'text'){
        console.log('true');
    }
}, false);
```

Of course I did `console.log(obj);` and it triggers fine on the body element, but no where else. Other than that it seems it only triggers once. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if this is even the right approach to do it. So I hope you guys can help me out.

Note: I know I can easily solve the problem with a click event instead, but anyone using Tab to go through the form elements would have an issue. So that's not a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind with window and allow the bubbling and you will get the element with target.

```js
window.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    if (e.target.id) console.log(e.target.id)
}, true);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tb1">
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="button">
<a href="#foo" id="link1">test</a>
```